# SAS - Issue with Arrays and transposing

Tags: arrays, sas, tabular

I'm trying to transpose a dataset however i'm getting the attached result in my table. I'm creating thee extra repeated rows but I'm not sure how to summarize my data so that there are only unique "test" labels and no blank GLH values [SASresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zCkw.png)

```
array leaners{*} Learners1-Learners3;       
do index = 1 to dim(leaners);   
  ind = index;          
  test = leaners{index};
  output;           
end;

array GLH{*} TotalGLHYear1-TotalGLHYear3;       
do index = 1 to dim(GLH);   
  ind = index;          
  GLHall = GLH{index};  
  output;           
end;


keep  Region test GLHall;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  For the first record, should there be 3 rows, each of which has one of the `test` and one of the `glhall` values?

Comment: I suspect that's really not what you want because you'll end up with duplicates. It would help if you included some sample data. I would suggest you search out a paper called a better way to transpose. It has a good macro that would be helpful in your situation. Or you can use a double proc transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You can save the distinct rows to a new table using proc sql:

```
proc sql;
create table work.want as
select distinct(*) from work.have ;
quit;
```

Option 2: You can remove duplicates from your table using proc sort:

```
proc sort data=work.have noduprecs;
by _all_ ; Run;
```